# Oracle APEX app import messes up page plug display points

Tags: oracle-apex

Using Oracle Application Express 4.2.5.00.08 we have the following recurring issue:

1. We develop on a development DB.
2. We export the whole application from the development DB to an SQL*Plus script file.
3. We import (via either SQL*Plus or APEX admin frontend, does not matter) the whole script file to a different (test/prod) DB.
4. Five (the same each time) of all page plugs get their display points messed up in the imported application.

The exported-from-DEV page plug creation snippet looks like:

```
declare
  s varchar2(32767) := null;
  l_clob clob;
  l_length number := 1;
begin
s:=s||'Revision Comments';

wwv_flow_api.create_page_plug (
  p_id=> 36035377787100554 + wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_flow_id=> wwv_flow.g_flow_id,
  p_page_id=> 68,
  p_plug_name=> 'Toolbar3',
  p_region_name=>'',
  p_parent_plug_id=>36001157224505179 + wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_escape_on_http_output=>'Y',
  p_plug_template=> 35698556626931435+ wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_plug_display_sequence=> 105,
  p_plug_new_grid         => false,
  p_plug_new_grid_row     => true,
  p_plug_new_grid_column  => true,
  p_plug_display_column=> null,
  p_plug_display_point=> 'REGION_POSITION_02',
  p_plug_item_display_point=> 'ABOVE',
  p_plug_source=> s,
  p_plug_source_type=> 'STATIC_TEXT',
  p_translate_title=> 'Y',
  p_plug_query_row_template=> 39496105155901584+ wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_plug_query_headings_type=> 'QUERY_COLUMNS',
  p_plug_query_num_rows => 15,
  p_plug_query_num_rows_type => 'NEXT_PREVIOUS_LINKS',
  p_plug_query_row_count_max => 500,
  p_plug_query_show_nulls_as => ' - ',
  p_plug_display_condition_type => 'SQL_EXPRESSION',
  p_plug_display_when_condition => ':P68_ID_BUS_DQI_DATA IS NOT NULL',
  p_pagination_display_position=>'BOTTOM_RIGHT',
  p_plug_customized=>'0',
  p_plug_caching=> 'NOT_CACHED',
  p_plug_comment=> '');
end;
/
```

When we export the whole app again from the test/production (after having it imported from the script file) and do a line-by-line comparison, the page plug's creation code snippet looks like...

```
declare
  s varchar2(32767) := null;
  l_clob clob;
  l_length number := 1;
begin
s:=s||'Revision Comments';

wwv_flow_api.create_page_plug (
  p_id=> 36035377787100554 + wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_flow_id=> wwv_flow.g_flow_id,
  p_page_id=> 68,
  p_plug_name=> 'Toolbar3',
  p_region_name=>'',
  p_parent_plug_id=>36001157224505179 + wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_escape_on_http_output=>'Y',
  p_plug_template=> 35698556626931435+ wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_plug_display_sequence=> 105,
  p_plug_new_grid         => false,
  p_plug_new_grid_row     => true,
  p_plug_new_grid_column  => true,
  p_plug_display_column=> null,
  p_plug_display_point=> 'BODY_3',
  p_plug_item_display_point=> 'ABOVE',
  p_plug_source=> s,
  p_plug_source_type=> 'STATIC_TEXT',
  p_translate_title=> 'Y',
  p_plug_query_row_template=> 39496105155901584+ wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
  p_plug_query_headings_type=> 'QUERY_COLUMNS',
  p_plug_query_num_rows => 15,
  p_plug_query_num_rows_type => 'NEXT_PREVIOUS_LINKS',
  p_plug_query_row_count_max => 500,
  p_plug_query_show_nulls_as => ' - ',
  p_plug_display_condition_type => 'SQL_EXPRESSION',
  p_plug_display_when_condition => ':P68_ID_BUS_DQI_DATA IS NOT NULL',
  p_pagination_display_position=>'BOTTOM_RIGHT',
  p_plug_customized=>'0',
  p_plug_caching=> 'NOT_CACHED',
  p_plug_comment=> '');
end;
/
```

... with the only difference being in the...

```
p_plug_display_point=> 'BODY_3',
```

... line.

This, of course, can be fixed manually via APEX frontend for each of the five page plugs, but that is unthinkable to do when 6 environments are in place and each of them should be updated several times a month. Automated deployment tools are in place for all DB development, only this APEX frontend must be taken care of by hand.

Comparison of the `apex_040200.wwv_flow_page_plugs` data before vs. after the manual, frontend-driven fix showed that only the `apex_040200.wwv_flow_page_plugs.plug_display_point` got updated from `'BODY_3'` back to `'REGION_POSITION_02'`. But we don't have privileges to do direct updates of the APEX tables.

I tried searching for some kind of `update_page_plug()` API procedure, but did not find any.

So, I'm interested in

- either finding the `update_page_plug()` procedure directly from APEX APIs,
- or fixing this directly in the application, so that the issues stop recurring (since I believe it is something that the original app's developer did not do right, just don't know what that might be).

Any advice, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't met the problem with newer versions of Apex, so hopefully you can upgrade the system to Apex 18 without to much of a hassle..

Alternatively, you can try modifying the original plugin initial  "p_plug_display_point=> 'REGION_POSITION_02'" into"
p_plug_display_point=> 'BODY_3'",
in the development environment, and use JS to reposition the added plugin content, this way when transferring the application to runtime you will not see the problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is not in the SQL\*Plus script file, the problem is in the database **after** importing the SQL\*Plus script file. And no, we cannot upgrade to newer APEX; DBAs do not pay much attention to APEX on their servers.

Comment: Pitty, and thanks for clarifying.
I edited my answer to something else that may help.